# Are there any possible ways to search multiple attribute in v-autocomplete in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I have an array of objects bind to item prop of v-autocomplete.
this is my data:

```
products: [
   {
      text: "Apple",
      value: 209
   },
   {
      text: "Banana",
      value: 229
   }
]

<v-autocomplete>
   ...
   :item="products"
   :search-input.sync="search"
</v-autocomplete>
```

so, i want to have the ability to search by both 'text' and 'value'. Currently, i am able to search only one among them.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom filter function to v-autocomplete as follows

```html
<v-autocomplete>
   ...
   :filter="customFilter"
   :item="products"
   :search-input.sync="search"
</v-autocomplete>
```

```js
methods: {
     customFilter (item, queryText, itemText) {
         // return true or false according to your logic
         // i.e queryText matches with item object
     },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can search multiple attribute using filter attribute which is provide in the docs:

```
  customSearch(item, queryText, itemText) {
      const data = item.text.toLowerCase() + item.value.toLowerCase()
      const searchText = queryText.toLowerCase()

      return textOne.indexOf(searchText) > -1 
  }
```

and use in the template like this:

```
 <v-autocomplete
     spellcheck="false" 
     :filter="customSearch"
...
</v-autocomplete>
```

Refer this docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props